# superfish not affected by css edits

Tags: theming

I am making a nav bar using the suckerfish module. I have installed the suckerfish module and have extracted the library into the necessary folders. I'd like to change the width of the individual columns in the nav, as some of my menu items are getting cut off. I'd also like to change the width of the nav bar as a whole, as it is not the same width as my header. However, when I try to make basic edits in the space-orange.css file, the edits do not seem to make any difference what-so-ever. I can change the style of the nav bar from the blocks menu, so I know the css files are in the right place. I have also looked at the suckerfish.css file, but it's not clear what, if anything, I could try to edit there. I am all out of ideas at this point. Are there any great tutorials out there pertaining to this? I can't seem to find any. Any help in getting me going in the right direction would be most useful and appreciated.

Thanks,

Kev

Comment: suggest that you inspect the nav bar with firebug to confirm which CSS loads the styles for the elements and once you've confirmed your changes are in the right file that they are visible, sometimes it might be a case of CSS Specificity when you try to override the styles.

Answer (score 0):

If some of your menu items are cut off, you should enable the supersubs plugin. You can do that on the block settings page for that particular menu.

If that's not what you want, copy over the stylesheets of superfish to your theme, include them in .info file and play around there.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent responses. I used the supersubs plugin to solve the issue. What is interesting, though, is that I had to make both numbers the same, in order to have any change to occur. Perhaps this is systematic of overriding something within the style sheet?

Comment: I didn't understand exactly; explain what do you mean by "making both numbers the same"